# Package installed with Composer not found by php install

Tags: php, xampp, composer-php

I have installed `prewk/xml-string-streamer` using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) into my Xampp PHP install, which lists the installation quite happy through the xampp command line. *However* when I try to use the package, PHP bugs out the same as it did before the install.  I'm trying to do the following:

`$streamer = Prewk\XmlStringStreamer::createStringWalkerParser($filename);`

as in the xml-string-streamer docs.

I feel I'm missing something obvious, and am aware this might be a specific problem with my setup, but I'm hoping I've missed a step or something.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Prewk\XmlStringStreamer' not found in ~\mainpage.php:23 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in ~\mainpage.php on line 23`

Line 23 is the one quoted in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md

I found the above page which answered most of my questions about how to get this to work.  I realised I'd installed the package, but not in the correct directory, nor had I included the correct `include` command to make it work.  I'm still getting errors but they appear to be from my buggy code-writing than this problem.

Sorry for wasting everyone's time.